# How can I fix this bug that causes me to be invincible?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim SE on PS4, there's enchanted armor/jewelry in my active effects that I've removed from my equipment but it keeps stacking as active effects! It's made me invincible and it's broken my game! I've tried everything I can think of but can't remove the active effects!! I can jump off High Hrothgar, live under water, stand in front of an entire army and I never take any damage. I'm currently not wearing anything enchanted, just plain clothes. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Are you running any [mods](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim?number_results=20&order=desc&page=1&platform=PS4&product=skyrim)?

Comment: Have you tried reverting to an earlier save?